# Finding the Coordinated for $y=x^2+5x-4$ where the gradient is equal to $3$.

Tags: geometry, derivatives

I've been back tracking through old work & came across this straightforward question:
*"Find the Coordinates of the point on the equation $$y=x^2+5x-4$$ where the gradient (m) is 3."*

The textbook lists the answer to the question as being **(-1,-8)**. However, I'm not getting the same solution. Is the textbook incorrect or have I overlooked something?

I attempted:
$$y'=x+5$$
thus $$x+5=3$$
$$x=-2$$
Substituted the Cord's X value:
$$y = (-2)^2+5(-2)-4$$
$$y = -10$$
Thus the cords are: $$(-2,-10)$$ 
What have I overlooked? The correct answer is supposed to be *(-1,-8)*

Comment: what is $dy/dx= m =x+5$??Are you sure you about the derivative?

Comment: $y' =dy/dx \neq x+5$ !!!

Comment: D;   I just saw.. 2x+5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.
Therefore your calculations would be:

$$y' = 2x + 5$$
$$2x + 5 = 3$$
$$x = -1, \text{ so that } y=-8$$

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to use mathjax/latex to typeset formulas on this site.